# newly added key causing not authorized error

Tags: heroku, ssh

I've created a new ssh key, added it to my ssh keys locally, then added it to heroku. When I try to push, I get a 'not authorized' error. I'm not sure what to do next...

```
~/app> heroku keys:add /home/user/.ssh/XXX-YYY-ZZZ.pub
Uploading SSH public key /home/user/.ssh/XXX-YYY-ZZZ.pub... done

~/app> heroku keys
=== mail+heroku@mydomain.com Keys
ssh-rsa xxxx zzz@ubuntu
ssh-rsa yyyy zzz@ubuntu

~/app> ssh-add /home/user/.ssh/XXX-YYY-ZZZ
\Enter passphrase for /home/user/.ssh/XXX-YYY-ZZZ: 
Identity added: /home/user/.ssh/XXX-YYY-ZZZ (/home/user/.ssh/XXX-YYY-ZZZ)

~/app> git push heroku master

 !  Your key with fingerprint XXXXX is not authorized to access XXX-YYY-ZZZ.

fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
```

Do I have to connect that key to my XXX-YYY-ZZZ app somehow? I don't see anything about that in the docs here https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/keys.

May be related, I have two heroku accts that I'm deploying to, this one that's failing is the second one. I'd like to keep them separate. I suspect the issue is with my ssh_config but I'm not sure how to solve it yet.

Comment: What OS are you on? Are you using a ssh manager, like `ssh-add`?

Comment: Ubuntu 10. Yes, ssh-add is in my sample code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like there's a plugin for heroku that will deal with this:

https://github.com/ddollar/heroku-accounts